# Delphi 10.2 – редактор кода, ширина текста «съехала»

Tags: delphi

Не знаю почему, но в одном из модулей, в редакторе кода длинна текста стала не больше 80 символов. Текст превышающий эту длинну перешел на вторую строку. Стало так **НЕ** удобно.
Как откатить изменения обратно?
У меня конечно стояло до этого ограничение длинны в 80 символов. Я конечно увеличил ограничение, но это ничего не дало.

Comment: Наверно это потому что вы нажали `Ctrl+D`? Вернуть можно если у вас во вкладочке History сохранились изменения до форматирования. Если нет, то ни как.

Comment: Да, но я думал идет ограничение, потому что в *"Tools->Options->Editor Options->Display" "Right margins"* стоит значение "80". Ага ни фига, хоть "180", всеравно ограничит на "80"

Comment: Что-то странное у вас творится. Может, какой-либо плагин для IDE чудит? Display right margin не ограничивает текст по ширине, эта опция только показывает правую границу пунктиром. А писать можно и далее совершенно спокойно. Скорее всего, вы имеете ввиду именно форматирование кода. Это Tools - Options - Formatter - Delphi - Line breaks - Right margin